# How to change image-background after sometime?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, html, css

HI everybody

i need to know if there are a way to change the background image after a specific time like 10 sec or 30 sec...etc.
you know like yahoo Login mail "it's changing the background daily!!"

if there is a way using JQuery or CSS or html or any other thing ,please tell me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can make it with javascript function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var imageID=0;
function changeimage(every_seconds){
    //change the image
    if(!imageID){
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="http://www.all-freeware.com/images/full/38943-nice_feathers_free_screensaver_desktop_screen_savers__nature.jpeg";
        imageID++;
    }
    else{if(imageID==1){
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="http://www.hickerphoto.com/data/media/186/flower-bouquet-nice_12128.jpg";
        imageID++;
    }else{if(imageID==2){
        document.getElementById("myimage").src="http://www.photos.a-vsp.com/fotodb/14_green_cones.jpg";
        imageID=0;
    }}}
    //call same function again for x of seconds
    setTimeout("changeimage("+every_seconds+")",((every_seconds)*1000));
}
</script>
</head>
<body style='background:black;' onload='changeimage(2)'>
<div style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;' align='center'><img width='300px' height='250px' id='myimage' src='http://www.photos.a-vsp.com/fotodb/14_green_cones.jpg'/></div>
</body></html>
```

try this one! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could probably achieve it using CSS3 webkit animations but the trade off is it will only work in the likes of Chrome and Safari but you won't require any JavaScript at all.

The jQuery suggestion above is your best bet here I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript's `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to do this, or look into [JQuery's Timers](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers)

**EDIT:**
With JQuery, this will change the background after 1 sec:

```
$(window).oneTime(1000, function() {
    // change your background image here
  });
```

Comment: i really want to use JQuery to solve this one but can you give me a sample page for this one please :(

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a function and setTimeout:

```
function changeBG()
{
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.style.backgroundImage = "url(myimage.gif)";
    setTimeout("changeBG",30000); // Change every 30 seconds
}

window.onload = changeBG;
```

(untested so it might need a tweak or 2)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) library:

```
var changeBackground = function() {
   $$('body').first().setStyle({
      backgroundImage: 'newImage.jpg'
   });
};
changeBackground.delay(15);
```