# Update background images periodically in the Hero unit of twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I implemented a twitter bootstrap hero unit successfully . I was thinking to animate the background of the hero unit to change every few seconds with a different image . I was able to make the background static using css . Is there a way to animate the background ?

I found this link useful [carousel behind hero-unit](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-bootstrap/CeTul_sWJos)

However the SO link [How to change image-background after sometime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820853/how-to-change-image-background-after-sometime) looks good to change the entire body of the html page but i want to restrict myself to only the hero-unit . Moreover there is no `onload` method for hero-unit .

Any suggestions anyone ?

Comment: You must have tried something? You could use CSS3 transitions or if you're not adverse to adding a framework into your project, maybe jQuery.

Comment: @DavidBarker yes i tried to follow the suggestion in the SO link . However as i said there is no `onload` method for hero unit else that would have been good enough for me . And yes i havent yet explored jquery . Stuck to javascript

Comment: The example you gave doesn't animate, it just changes the image. Do you definitely want an animation, such as fading in/out?

Comment: @DavidBarker nope sorry i dont want animation . I updated my question . I need image change .

Comment: Ok, post the code up with what you have tried whilst implementing the solution in the other SO answer. That JS would do exactly what you need and it's likely just a bug in your code. :-)

Comment: @DavidBarker yes i fixed it massive bug in my code :P thanks !